# android call a timer run function from widget

Tags: java, android

i have a timer in my widget that runs every 10 minutes, but i need to call the timers run function when I press a button. is any way of doing that?

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }
    } else {
  // check, if our Action was called
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
            //call the run function of the timer
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ) {

    if(tt==0) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1000, 600000);
        tt=1;
    }
}

private class MyTime extends TimerTask {


    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            }
```

i need to cal that function from onReceive()

Comment: "i have a timer in my widget that runs every 10 minutes" -- no, you do not. Android can and will terminate your process in between app widget updates. When Android terminates your process, your `Timer` and `TimerTask` go away. Hence, your `TimerTask` may never be invoked. If you wish to update an app widget every 10 minutes, please use `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method in the MyWidget class and call it from both the run method in MyTime and onReceive like this:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
            }
        } else {
            // check, if our Action was called
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
                //call the run function of the timer
                doStuff();
            }
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ) {
        if(tt==0) {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1000, 600000);
            tt=1;
        }
    }

    private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
        public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doStuff();
        }
    }

    private void doStuff() {
        // Stuff that needs to be done in run and onReceive
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What run method are you referring to ?

There is no run method in class Timer()

If your trying to execute the run method in class MyTime, start it via a thread since TimerTask implements Runnable -

```
  if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
        //call the run function of the timer
        MyTime myTime = new MyTime();
        Thread thread = new Thread(myTime);
        thread.start();
    }
```